# Find Expectation of min function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

ξ is normally distributed on the (0,1]. find Expectation of η=min(ξ,2/3).

Any ideas how to solve ?

Comment: "Normally distributed" usually refers to a specific (family of) distribution(s) on the whole of $\Bbb R$. Perhaps you meant "uniformly distributed"?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

$$E(\eta)=\int_0^{1}\min\left(\xi,\frac23\right)p(\xi)\,d\xi=\int_0^{2/3}\xi\,p(\xi)\,d\xi+\int_{2/3}^1\frac23\,p(\xi)\,d\xi.$$

The final result will depend on the exact expression of $p$, which is unclear at the time of this writing.

---

Knowing the $\text{cdf}$, let $P$, you can use

$$\int_0^{2/3}\xi\,p(\xi)\,d\xi+\int_{2/3}^1\frac23\,p(\xi)\,d\xi=\left.\xi\,P(\xi)\right|_0^{2/3}-\int_0^{2/3}P(\xi)\,d\xi+\frac23\left.P(\xi)\right|_0^{2/3}$$ but this still requires to integrate $P$.